# Problema com validates no Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4

Tenho uma situção que não consigo entender o que está errado.
Tenho uma validação no model que pelo console ela funciona corretamente, mas ao executar pelo browser o formulario faz o submit e ignora a validação.

Meu Model:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

```
validates :name, presence: true

has_secure_password
```

end

Estou quebrando a cabeça.

Comment: Tem como exibir o params?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o meu problema, na verdade o formulário pelo browser estava validando só que quando dava erro para salvar no meu controller eu estava fazendo um "render :plain" para retornar a mensagem de erro, então desta forma o erro do validates não era exibido.
O que eu fiz foi alterar o meu controller para fazer o seguinte em caso de erro renderiza o form novamente.

```
def create        
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        redirect_to @users
    else
        render '_form'
    end
end
```